# EF code-first migration via web deploy package not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi2 project that I'm deploying to my development server via a web deploy package. I used the WebApi scaffolding with MVC, and did successfully create an initial migration for the user-related tables.

Everything worked fine until I accidentally added a controller with EF & actions, using the wrong model. I deleted the controller, but something must have been created by EF behind the scenes, because now every time I try to access the Api I get the following error:

```
The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. 
Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.
```

I looked at the Migrations folder, but there are no changes in there.

I checked my source control, but I can't see any changes in there, either.

I have tried setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true in my configuration class, but that didn't seem to do anything at all.

I tried calling Update-Database from the package manager console, but that's looking for the Db in the App_Data directory, whereas the correct Db is hosted on my local instance of SQL Server, so that failed.

I even tried to add a new migration, but that fails with the following error:

```
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201603181320388_Initial]
```

Looking at the database I can see the tables that were created by that migration, so I'm pretty sure that's also due to EF not seeing the correct Db.

I tried changing the connection string in my project's web.config file to the one from the deployed web.config file in an attempt to make EF look at the correct file location, but no joy.

I'm pretty new at using EF, so the answer is probably something obvious, but I can't see it.

Is there maybe a way to see what has been changed in EF and undo it? Or can I specify the path to the database for the Update-Database command?

Comment: EF will, by default, look for a connection string with the same name of your context class in your web.config file. If it's not connecting to the db, you should check your connection string.

Comment: @VitorRigoni Thanks, but I've double-checked the connection string and it seems fine. What bothers me most is that I don't know were the information to change the model is hidden. I thought all changes to the DbContext were contained in the Migrations folder when using the code-first approach, but there's nothing there that wasn't before.

Comment: Did you ever fix this @FraukeNonnenmacher?

Comment: @Worthy7: No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: *FYI:*
When using the PMConsole to do migrations, it will connect to the database defined by whatever APP/WEB.config file is in your STARTUP project. It will search for the string using any DbContext classes defined in the project selected at the top of the console window. Usually you have a context class which inherits from DbContext("name=something") That something is the db name it will search for in the config of the startup project.

Comment: @Worthy7, thank you, that's good to know. I ended up creating a new project/DB to get around the problem.